# D3 - Add data points using data in chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-one-y-axis?embed=1&file=src/app/bar-chart.ts&hideNavigation=1

I have a stacked bar chart with line chart on top.

The bar chart and line chart have two different data sets and I'm using a seond y-axis to plot the line chart data.

The line chart points are the totals for the two stacked charts in each months column.

Instead of having separate data and y-axis for the line chart is it possible to add up the data from the each months stacked bar and plot that on the graph using one y axis

Comment: Yes it is possible. Have you tried any code to do that? How about using [d3.nest](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/) to nest the data based on month and add up the values and then use it to stack the bars based on the keys? It'd be appreciated if you could try and get back.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved in several ways. You can either redefine `line.x`, `.y` and `.defined` accessors using all three `d`, `i`, `data` arguments or you can map the data like this:

```
.data(
    linedata.reduce(function(acc, current, index) {
        let isFirstPair = index % 2 === 0;
        let currentDate = that.y1(current.date)
        let currentValue = that.y1(current.value)

        if (isFirstPair) {
            acc.push({ date: currentDate, value: currentValue });
        } else {
            acc[acc.length - 1].value += currentValue;
        }

        return acc;
    }, [])
)
```

It will create a new object for every consequent pair in the source array. You may need to tweak the date or `.x` accessor.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - where would this fit in my example?

Comment: You can start with replacing `.data([linedata])` with it (`bar-chart.ts`, line 273).